# UseState and useContext does not work together in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I tried to use context api with useState hook. I could not wire together with typescript :(

First create App.tsx:

```
const App = () => {

    const [exampleId, updateExampleId] = useState(0);

return ( 
 <div>
   <ExampleContext.Provider value={ [exampleId, updateExampleId]}>
        <ExampleList/>
   </ExampleContext.Provider>
</div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Then I added ExampleList.tsx:

```
function ExampleList() {

    const {exampleId, updateExampleId} = useContext(ExampleContext);

 const handleListItemClick = (
        event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>,
        id: number,
    ) => {
        // How can I call updateExample to set id to exampleId?
        updateExampleId();
    };

    return (
        <List component="nav">
            {examples.map((example) =>
                <ListItem button
                          key={example.id}
                          selected={...}
                          onClick={event => handleListItemClick(event, example.id)}>
                    <ListItemText
                       Example Text
                    />
                </ListItem>
            )
            }
        </List>

    );
```

And also have Context. How can I create typed context? Is it necessary? I tried to use it like this:

```
export interface ContextType {
    exampleId: number,
    updateExampleId: (value: number) => {}
}

// React.createContext< ContextType > ???
export const ExampleContext = React.createContext({
    exampleId: 0,
    updateExampleId: () => {}
});


export default ExampleContext ;
```

Comment: Fortunately I could solve it. After added types and default values to context and useState, it works well.

Comment: can you show what you used for types?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe `<ExampleContext.Provider value={ {exampleId, updateExampleId} }>`

Comment: You wrote *Maybe `<...`* but have you tested it?   OP wrote in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60297132/#comment107456648_60297132) *Fortunately I could solve it. After added types and default values to context and useState, it works well* so it seems like they fixed this in a different way.